# Cannot find module 'typescript/bin/tsc' when running tsc-watch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, tsc

Getting "Cannot find module 'typescript/bin/tsc'" when I try to run tsc-watch

`yarn tsc-watch --noClear -p tsconfig.json`

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ /Users/jason/Work/VDQ/VDQApp/node_modules/.bin/tsc-watch --noClear -p tsconfig.json
Cannot find module 'typescript/bin/tsc'
Require stack:
- /Users/jason/Work/VDQ/VDQApp/node_modules/tsc-watch/lib/tsc-watch.js
- /Users/jason/Work/VDQ/VDQApp/node_modules/tsc-watch/index.js
```

the error is reproducible simply without the JSBundling/package.json /Yarn setup

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.1.0",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.2.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.10",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "tsc": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets",
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules",
    "failure:js": "rm ./app/assets/builds/application.js && rm ./app/assets/builds/application.js.map",
    "compile:typescript": "tsc-watch --noClear -p tsconfig.json --onSuccess \"yarn build\" --onFailure \"yarn failure:js\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tsc-watch": "^5.0.3"
  }
}
```

my tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you fail to globally add the typescript package using

Confusingly, the typescript command is invoked using `tsc` but the package name is `typscript`

TO FIX:

`yarn global add typescript`

or

`npx install -g typescript`

Comment: It should be `yarn global add typescript`